# Ocultar formulario cuando le doy clic a un botón

Tags: html, angularjs, layout, botón

Buenos días! Como siempre estoy con un proyecto en Angularjs. El problema que tengo es que no se como ocultar el formulario cuando le doy clic al botón 'información'.

Este es el código del formulario que quiero ocultar:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">

        <form action="http://localhost:58498/api/Cuota" class="form-horizontal"
              method="get" role="form" id="formulario-cuotas">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="Cuotas">¿Cuánto quieres pedir?</label>
                <input class="form-control" data-val="true"
                       data-val-cuotas="El campo de las Cuotas está vacío. No es válido"
                       data-val-required="El campo Cuotas es obligatorio." id="Cuotas"
                       name="cantidad" type="number" value=""
                       ng-model="formulario.cantidad">
                <span class="field-validation-valid text--danger"
                      data-valmsg-for="Cuotas" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>

            <p>
                "Con el préstamo 24h puedes pedir a partir <br>
                de 500€, pero para cantidades de hasta 3000€ <br>
                tiene que ser en la "<a href="/es/tarjetas/tarjetas-credito/tarjeta-visa-clip" target="_blank">
                    modalidad de
                    tarjeta <br>
                </a>
                ".Por eso este simulador empieza en 3000€ que <br>
                es lo mínimo que puedes pedir en la modalidad <br>
                de préstamo. Ten en cuenta que no puedes <br>
                solicitar más de lo que cuesta lo que vayas <br>
                financiar."
            </p>


            <br>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Plazo" class="control-label">¿Cuándo deseas devolverlo?</label>
                <input class="form-control" data-val="true"
                       data-val-cuotas="El campo de los plazos está vacío. No es válido"
                       data-val-required="El campo Plazos es obligatorio." id="Plazos"
                       name="plazos" type="text" value=""
                       ng-model="formulario.plazos">
                <span class="field-validation-valid text--danger"
                      data-valmsg-for="Plazos" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>

            <p>
                "Puedes devolverlo en un plazo maximo de 96 meses,<br>
                osea, 8 años"
            </p>



                    <div class="form-check">
                        <label class="form-check-label" ng-repeat="option in radioOptions">
                            <input type="radio" ng-model="formulario.tipo" value="{{option.value}}" ng-required="!formulario.tipo" ng-value="true">
                            {{option.name}}

                        <br>
                        </label>

                    </div>
            <br>
            <br>

 </form>
       <div>
            <div>
                <button ng-click="myForm()">
                    NG-ENVIAR
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="col-md-6">
        <div ng-show="showMe">

            <div>

                <respuesta datos="contenedor"></respuesta>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Y este es el botón que quiero usar para ocultar el formulario:

```
<body ng-app="App">
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top " style="background-color:#5882FA">
    <div class="container" style="color:white">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" style="color:#ffffff">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @*@Html.ActionLink("Información", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand"})*@
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a ui-sref="solicitud">Solicitud</a></li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("API", "Index", "Help", new { area = "HelpPage" }, null)</li>
                <li><a ui-sref="informacion">Informacion</a></li>
            </ul>
            @*@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")*@

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@*style="padding-top:0px;*@
@*"container text-center"*@
@*class="body-content"*@




<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    @RenderSection("SPAViews", required: false)
    <hr />
    <footer>

        <div class="container text-center" style="padding-top:20px;" ui-view></div>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>

    </footer>
</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/banco")

@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

Perdonad si pongo mucho código pero es para que lo podáis entender mejor. 
Realmente solo quiero usar la opción de 'información' para hacer que se oculte el formulario:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" style="color:#ffffff">

<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

 <li><a ui-sref="informacion">Informacion</a></li>

 <div class="container text-center" style="padding-top:20px;" ui-view></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes realizar mediante el atributo `ng-click` y los atributos `ng-hide` y `ng-show`.

Ejemplo:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="">
  <button ng-click="ocultar=true">Ocultar</button>
  <button ng-click="ocultar=false">Mostrar</button> 

    <form ng-hide="ocultar">
      <input type="text" value="Este formulario se oculta">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Esto lo añado después del <li> ?

Comment: @SilviaGarcia Simplemente añade el elemento `ng-click="ocultar=true"` en el elemento en el que al hacer click quieras ocultar el formulario y `ng-hide="ocultar"` en el formulario que quieras ocultar.

Comment: vale, muchas gracias!